# Differential copy from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, rsync, scp

Is there any way to do differential copies of a directory from Windows to Linux over ssh, sftp, scp, or similar? Preferably not rsync since they are all cygwin based and force you to use the /cygdrive/c/... file path convention which is a pain.  I'm trying to frequently upload new code to a Raspberry Pi and have been using pscp but it doesn't allow differential copies or excluding directories/files, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Moses I don't think it qualifies as a product recommendation question now.

Answer (score 2):

[Unison](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) is a well-established, open-source tool for this.  It has pre-compiled binaries for Linux, native Windows, and Cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

I personnaly use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php) to make this. It's pretty easy to script or use graphically.

Comment: This is really more of a suggested direction to a solution than a solution.  As is, it would be more appropriate as a comment.  Please see this link on how to recommend software in an answer: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers

Comment: This answer implies "yes" none can be exhaustive on such answer than giving examples.